# Card hover animation scale background

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I'm trying to make a hover effect on my card, but I can't imagine basically when it's on hover I need my image to occupy 100% of my height and my text to change color
something like this:

[image]

code:

```
<Div
  onMouseOver={() => setisHover(true)}
  onMouseOut={() => setisHover(false)}
  isHover={isHover}
>
  <div className="bg-img" />
  <div className="text">
    <h3>Testing</h3>
  </div>
</Div>
```

css:

```
const Div = styled.div`
  margin: 50px;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 50vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  & .bg-img {
    height: 50%;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557683316-973673baf926?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80");
  }
  & .text {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
`;
```

I'm basically not able to scale my image without exceeding my maximum height

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-ardinghelli-i4t2p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should place them with `position:absolute` and play with it.

check here the updated code

https://codesandbox.io/embed/sparkling-sun-h66es?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: hello basically i need the image to have a scale that does not exceed the total height and is 100% of the height
Would you help me out of this?

Comment: I've tried all the ways with the scale so that the image is 100% of the height on hover and the text on it but I couldn't

Comment: Oh, i see now. doe's the card have a fixed height? (as in the example)

Comment: that and then on hover my image is 100% tall and my text on the image as the example image

Comment: omg thanks a lot that was exactly it
could you help me with just one more thing?
how could I add a fade effect to the text when changing the color

Comment: just play with the transitions. look at the code now